# Mocking From Repository Returns Null

Tags: c#, moq

I'm new to Mocking and not sure if I'm doing this correctly. I'm trying to use the function `WriteNameToDatabase` which uses the `GetName` method so I have my classes setup like so:

My Employee Interface:

```
public interface IEmployee
{
    Task<string> GetName();
   string WriteNameToDataBase();

}
```

My Employee Class

```
 public class Employee : IEmployee
    {
        public Task<string> GetName()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string WriteNameToDataBase()
        {
            var employeeName = GetName();

            return $"Wrote {employeeName.Result} to database";

        }
```

My Unit Test Class

```
 [Test]

    public void WriteToDBShouldWrite()
    {
        var mockObject = new Mock<IEmployee>();
        mockObject.Setup(x => x.GetName()).ReturnsAsync("Frank");

        string result = mockObject.Object.WriteNameToDataBase();

        Assert.AreEqual("Wrote Frank to database", result);

    }
```

This always returns me `Was Expecting 'Wrote Frank to database` but was actually null` or something to that effect that Assert gives me. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Edit: Corrected to use `ReturnsAsync("Frank");`

Comment: Yoru problem is: Both GetName and WriteNameToDataBase are mocked. Because of this, when you call WriteToNameToDatabase, you will never call GetName.

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean about Mocking both, because I'm mocking `IEmployee`. How do I work around this If I'm trying just to test my `WriteNameToDatabase` Task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you're creating a Mock object based on the interface `IEmployee` not the Class `Employee`, so you're not testing your `Employee` class at all, therefore you cannot expect any code in the `Employee` class to be run.

You need to think about what your test is actually trying to do, and what constitutes a "unit" in your project.

You could create a new interface `INameGetter` (or something with a name that makes sense to your project) which contains the `GetName` method. You could then take this new interface as a dependency in your employee class and mock it out in your test. Something like:

```
public interface IEmployee
{
   Task<string> WriteNameToDataBase();
}

public interface INameGetter
{
   Task<string> GetName();
}

public class Employee : IEmployee
{
     private INameGetter nameGetter;

     public Employee(INameGetter n)
     {
         nameGetter = n;
     }

    public Task<string> WriteNameToDataBase()
    {
        var employeeName = await nameGetter.GetName();

        return $"Wrote {employeeName} to database";
    }
}
```

And your test method

```
[Test]
public void WriteToDBShouldWrite()
{
    var mockObject = new Mock<INameGetter>();
    mockObject.Setup(x =>  x.GetName()).Returns(Task.FromResult("Frank"));

    string result =  new Employee(mockObject.Object).WriteNameToDataBase();

    Assert.AreEqual("Wrote Frank to database", result);

}
```

N.B You alse need to look into async/await for using methods returning `Task`. Edit: I've now fixed it here, but essentially you don't want to be using `Task.Result`.

Comment: Makes sense, I marked this as the answer. Although how does something like this make sense if multiple devs are trying to test mutiple different things; they would have to do this for every method that isn't implemented?

Comment: @Frank This is where your definition of 'Unit' becomes important. You don't necessarily need separate unit tests for each method. It could be in your example that it makes sense to test both your methods in one test (therefore no mocking would be required). I think you would find reading up about SOLID principle very helpful.

Comment: This is missing a `await` on the async call. If you don't add this it will deadlock.

Comment: @Liam copied from OP, but will edit. Have made a note at the bottom of answer

Answer (score 4):

Several problems, one your not awaiting your async call:

```
    public async Task<string> WriteNameToDataBase()
    {
        var employeeName = await GetName();

        return $"Wrote {employeeName} to database";

    }
```

two your mocking the result wrong, moq supports async:

```
mockObject.Setup(x => x.GetName()).ReturnsAsync("Frank");
```

But **the big issue here is** your mocking the entire object. This isn't testing anything. You probably want something more like:

```
public class Employee : IEmployee
{
    private readonly INameRepo _repo;
    public Employee(INameRepo repo)
    {
         //this is dependancy injection
         _repo = repo;
    }

    public async Task<string> WriteNameToDataBase()
    {
        var employeeName = await _repo.GetName();

        return $"Wrote {employeeName.Result} to database";

    }
 }
```

Your repo is now a separate thing represented by this interface

```
public interface INameRepo
{
      Task<string> GetName();
}
```

Then your test looks like:

```
[Test]
//note this is also async now
public async Task WriteToDBShouldWrite()
{
    //mock the dependencies
    var mockObject = new Mock<INameRepo>();
    mockObject.Setup(x => x.GetName()).ReturnsAsync("Frank");

    //test the actual object
    Employee emp = new Employee(mockObject.Object);
    string result = await emp.WriteToDBShouldWrite();

    Assert.AreEqual("Wrote Frank to database", result);

}
```

If you just want to verify that `GetName` is called you should be using `Verify` instead of returning an arbitrary value:

```
[Test]
//note this is also async now
public async Task WriteToDBShouldWrite()
{
    var mockObject = new Mock<INameRepo>();
    mockObject.Setup(x => x.GetName()).ReturnsAsync("Frank");

    string result = mockObject.Object.WriteNameToDataBase();

    Employee emp = new Employee(mockObject.Object);
    await emp.WriteToDBShouldWrite();

    //ensure GetName is called once and once only
    mockObject.Verify(v => v.GetName(), TimesOnce);

}
```